# Usar função JavaScript dentro de uma coluna de tabela PHP

Tags: php, javascript, funções, tabela-html

Olá,

Estou chamando um arquivo JS no meu index.php:

```
<script src="./Arquivos/js/ddtf.js"></script>
```

E dentro de um echo preciso aplicar a função que existe dentro dele:

```
<td><?php echo '<script>ddTableFilter('.$row['nome_cliente'].');</script>'?></td>
```

Esse arquivo JS aplica um check box para filtrar na coluna da tabela o nome selecionado. Alguém sabe onde está o erro ?

O apache não retornar nenhum erro, somente não exibe nenhum campo na coluna

Comment: O apontamento do JS está ok ? De qualquer forma tente assim : `<?php print ddTableFilter($row['nome_cliente']) ;?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente chamar a função dessa forma

```
<td>
   <script>ddTableFilter('<?php echo $row["nome_cliente"]; ?>')</script>
</td>
```

apenas lembre de verificar se a função já esta declarada.

Answer (score 1):

Chame a função dentro do script, ficaria assim

```
<td>
    <script>ddTableFilter(<?php echo $row['nome_cliente']; ?> )</script>
</td>
```